# Python PyQt5 QGraphicsView catch wheel event

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

In python I have build an .ui file with a QGraphicsView using the QDesigner.

In the Python-script I now would like to catch, when the mouse wheel is used in the widget. However, the script does not catch the event.

Any help?

```
class Klassenname(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Klassenname, self).__init__()
        self.UI = loadUi(self.gui)
        self.update()  # Calling the update function

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.UI.graphicsView.wheelEvent(self, event)  # self.UI.graphicsView is the widget
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.zoomIn()  # function for zooming in 
        else:
            self.zoomOut()  # function for zooming out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Klassenname()
    win.UI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The .ui file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>781</width>
      <height>561</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share the .ui....

Comment: Updated the question with the .ui file

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not know several concepts so I will explain what loadUi does, if you do not pass it a second argument then a new window will be created (in your case "self.UI") that is different from "win" so the wheel event does not it will be transferred from "self.UI" to "win" so the wheelEvent method of "win" is not called.

So first you must make "Klassenname" be the displayed window and for this you must pass "self".

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class Klassenname(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Klassenname, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("/path/of/your_file.ui", self)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.zoomIn()
        else:
            self.zoomOut()
        return super(Klassenname, self).wheelEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Klassenname()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With the code you will listen to the events of the mouse wheel that receives "Klassenname" but if you only want to listen to the mouse events of QGraphicsView then you must use an eventFilter:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class Klassenname(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Klassenname, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("/path/of/your_file.ui", self)
        self.graphicsView.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.graphicsView and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                self.zoomIn()
            else:
                self.zoomOut()
        return super(Klassenname, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Klassenname()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: While we are at it, here is some better logic (albeit C++) to handle wheel event in graphics view:  `auto anchor = transformationAnchor();
 setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
 auto angle = event->angleDelta().y();
 qreal factor = std::pow(1.2, angle / 240.0);
 scale(factor, factor);
 setTransformationAnchor(anchor);`

Comment: @ypnos The question only wants to detect the mouse wheel event, and from there how you want to use that information is another story that is not covered by my answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much, it works. Yet when zooming in, if then the mouse wheel is turned the other way, it moves the content until it reaches the bottom edge of the png and then scrolls out again.

Comment: @eyllanesc I just wanted provide some code that might be a typical follow-up to that question: How to zoom with mouse wheel in the graphics view as the user typically expects it. Not a criticism of your answer at all.

Comment: @user12523066 The question was specific: *QGraphicsView catch wheel event*, so I will only answer that, if you have another problem then investigate first, and if you still do not find a problem then create a new question explaining your research and showing what you have tried.

Comment: @ypnos mmm, I have another point of view: The comments are not used to follow-up but to discuss the solution, for example: when it may fail, or if it no longer works for a current version, problems with the implementation of the solution, etc. .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :-)